# Locally evaluate nonlinear dynamic system's stability using eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems, computational-mathematics

I don't have a large mathematical background, but I'm working with Computational Neuroscience. I have a large Synaptic Matrix (x axis: presynaptic NeuronID, y axis: postsynaptic NeuronID) in a Modular network. This matrix is close to a random one and Girko's circular law applies partly, in the sense that the bulk of the eigenvalues lies in a circle when you plot their Imag/Real parts; some eigenvalues will be outside the bulk because of the network's modularity ([1](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0054383#pone-0054383-g009)).

Moreover, my system is nonlinear since it is composed of neurons, whose population activity's transfer function is close to a sigmoid [(2)](http://neuronaldynamics.epfl.ch/online/x316.png).

Can I derive some conclusions about my system's stability (locally at least) based on the eigenvalues? For instance, if I have a large real eigenvalue, my system could prove to be unstable, with exponentially increased activity over time..

Comment: Is your system continuous of discrete? In the first case stability is ensured if the real part of all your eigenvalues is negative while in the latter case the eigenvalues should be located within the unit circle.

Comment: The transfer function is Frequency/Input in continuous time. The synaptic matrix is sparse (like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByAtIC3JJ5OAYnJpeGFDdEdlS1E&authuser=0) ). So if there exist some positive real parts, then the system is unstable? Aren't they "cancelled out" by the respective negative ones?

Comment: Yes, it is unstable if one eigenvalue has positive real part.  Because when we solve the respective ODEs there will be terms $e^{Re\lambda_i t}$ that will grow with time if $Re\lambda_i>0$ and repel the state trajectories from the equilibrium point.

Comment: @CTNT is the stability condition that you mention a "if and only if" condition?

Comment: Yes, the equilibrium is asymptotically stable if and only if all eigenvalues have negative real part. For marginal stability (bounded trajectories after a perturbation) you can have eigenvalues on the imaginary axis (under certain conditions).

Answer (score 1):

Linear stability analysis for a discrete dynamical system only make sense close to an equilibrium whose e.v. are all strictly inside the unit ball (have negative real parts) as pointed out CTNT.

In general usually for highly nonlinear systems like yours stability analysis via linearisation does not work. If you have eigenvalues with modulus very close to $1$ (real part close to $0$ in continuous case) you might expect some periodicity to occur in your system.

If you really expect very strong stability (that every solution in the interesting set converges to a particular equilibrium) you might try to construct a Lyapunov function. Whether it is possible to do for large systems of interacting neurons -- I have no idea.

Numerically people often compute Lyapunov exponents -- if all of them are less ore equal than zero, the system is considered stable. But this is not rigorous in any sense.